# Blazor WebAssembly File Chunking directly to Azure Blob Storage using C# (no JavaScript)

Tags: c#, azure, blazor, azure-blob-storage, blazor-webassembly

I am using Blazor Webssembly and .Net 5.0. I need to be able to upload very large files (2-5GB) to Azure Blob Storage using chunking by uploading file data in stages and then firing a final commit message on the blob once all blocks have been staged.

I was able to achieve this using SharedAccessSignatures and the Azure JavaScript Libraries (there are many examples available online).

However I would like to handle this using pure C#. Where I am running into an issue is the IBrowserFile reference seems to try to load the entire file into memory rather than read in just the chunks it needs for each stage in the loop.

For simplicity sake my example code below does not include any Azure Blob Storage code. I am simply writing the chunking and commit messages to the console:

```
@page "/"

<InputFile OnChange="OnInputFileChange" />

@code{

async Task OnInputFileChange(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var file = e.File;

        int blockSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;//1 MB Block
        int offset = 0;
        int counter = 0;
        List<string> blockIds = new List<string>();

        using (var fs = file.OpenReadStream(5000000000))  //<-- Need to go up to 5GB
        {
            var bytesRemaining = fs.Length;
            do
            {
                var dataToRead = Math.Min(bytesRemaining, blockSize);
                byte[] data = new byte[dataToRead];
                var dataRead = fs.Read(data, offset, (int)dataToRead);
                bytesRemaining -= dataRead;
                if (dataRead > 0)
                {
                    var blockId = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(counter.ToString("d6")));
                    Console.WriteLine($"blockId:{blockId}");
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Block {0} uploaded successfully.", counter.ToString("d6")));
                    blockIds.Add(blockId);
                    counter++;
                }
            }
            while (bytesRemaining > 0);
            Console.WriteLine("All blocks uploaded. Now committing block list.");
            Console.WriteLine("Blob uploaded successfully!");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }

  }
}
```

This first issue is that is that:

**Synchronous reads are not supported.**

So I tried:

```
var fs = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
await file.OpenReadStream(5000000000).CopyToAsync(fs);

using (fs)
{
    ...
}
```

But obviously I am now going to run into memory issues! And I do. The error on even a 200kb file is:

**Out of memory**

And anything over 1MB:

**Garbage collector could not allocate 16384u bytes of memory for major heap section.**

Is there a way to read in smaller chunks of data at a time from the IBrowserFile so this can be achieved natively in client side Blazor without having to resort to JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

.NET 6.0 has a nice `Stream.CopyToAsync()` implementation, which can be found here
https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/io/stream.cs

This will copy the data from one stream to an other asynchronously.

The gist of it is this:

```
    private async Task CopyToAsyncInternal(Stream source, Stream destination, Int32 bufferSize, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = await source.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false)) != 0)
        {
            await destination.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytesRead, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
```

(copied from link above)

Set the `bufferSize` to something like 4096 or a multiple and it should work. Other values are also possible, but usually block are taken as a multiple of 4k.
The assumption here is that you have a writable stream to which you can write the bytes asynchronously. You can modify this loop to count blocks and to other stuff per block. In any case don't use a memory stream client side or server side with large files.