# Blazor WebAssembly CancellationToken on JSRuntime

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am trying to cancel a long running JavaScript process when a user navigates away from a page in Blazor WebAssembly. I am implementing IDisposable on the page and passing in a token when making the call to the JavaScript function.

On the Dispose method I am calling .Cancel() and .Dispose() on the token. However if I start the function and navigate away to another page the process still continues.

Here is some example code to show the issue I am running into. This is using the base Blazor WebAssembly template.

If you open the console window you will see that once you arrive to the "Counter" page I invoke the JavaScript method on OnInitializedAsync()  then if you use the menu to navigate to another page such as "Home" and wait for the timeout to be called it will still print to the console log.

**Here is my JavaScript:**

```
(function () {
    testFunctions = {
        testFunction1: function (arguments) {

            var message = arguments[0];
            var timeOutLength = arguments[1];

            setTimeout(function () {
                console.log(message);
            }, timeOutLength);

        }
    }
})();
```

**And the Razor Page:**

```
@page "/counter"
@inject IJSRuntime _jsRuntime
@implements IDisposable



@code {

    private System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource jsCancellationToken = new System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var args = new List<object>();
        args.Add("Hello!");
        args.Add(10000);

        var uploadResult = await _jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("testFunctions.testFunction1", jsCancellationToken.Token, args);

    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        jsCancellationToken.Cancel();
        jsCancellationToken.Dispose();
    }

}
```

My question is how can I completely kill this JavaScript process from continuing to run when I dispose the page?

Comment: I think you would need to call clearTimeout, which means you would need to store the value returned from setTimeout - and then have another function `cancelTestFunction1` that you call to cancel.

Comment: A `CancellationToken` doesn't abort calls. It's used for cooperative cancellation - to signal cancellation to another method. It's up to the method to stop and exit gracefully. In this case cancellation will cancel the wait on `InvokeAsync` but there's nothing to tell the JavaScript method it needs to exit

Comment: @INNVTV, use the function clearTimeout, as suggested by Mister Magoo. The easiest way to implement your code is by employing the  DotNetObjectReference object.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos How can I access the CancellationToken from my JavaScript? It does not seem to get passed in as a parameter.

Comment: @enet I am only using setTimeout() as an example running process. In a real world scenario (in my case a large file upload using chunks) we may not have a method for that.

Comment: `a large file upload using chunks` why don't you use C# for this? A file upload is either POST or FORM POST. Both can be done with HttpClient. Chunks and ranges are supported

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I wish I could. Running into an issue with files over 2GB. Here is my S.O. on the matter: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69090067/blazor-webassembly-file-chunking-directly-to-azure-blob-storage-using-c-sharp-n

Comment: @INNVTV, you can easily use events to implement this requirement, together with the DotNetObjectReference object... Add event listener to start the work, and remove the listener when a given condition is fulfilled. You may also use a Web Worker instead. All dependent on what you do.

Comment: Thanks @enet I will play around with that. If you want to submit an answer with working code feel free and if it works I can mark that as the answer.

Comment: @INNVTV, I'll try to create a complete solution in the following days if I have the spare time...

Answer (score 2):

From the comments, it appears that the long operation is downloading a 2GB file. Since there's no way for Blazor to write to disk, and there's no way to send a .NET Stream to Javascript (yet, the inverse is possible [in Blazor 6 Preview 7](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-net-6-preview-7/#blazor-streaming-interop-from-javascript-to-net)) that means we need to let JavaScript manage the entire download.

**Aborting in Javascript**

Aborting/cancellation in Javascript is provided by the [AbortController](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController) class which works similarly to a CancellationTokenSource. It provides an [AbortSignal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortSignal) through the `signal` property that's signaled when the [abort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController/abort) method is called.

The documentation example is relevant as it shows cancellation of a long `fetch` operation with `fetch(url, {signal})`:

```
var controller = new AbortController();
var signal = controller.signal;

var downloadBtn = document.querySelector('.download');
var abortBtn = document.querySelector('.abort');

downloadBtn.addEventListener('click', fetchVideo);

abortBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  controller.abort();
  console.log('Download aborted');
});

function fetchVideo() {
  ...
  fetch(url, {signal}).then(function(response) {
    ...
  }).catch(function(e) {
   reports.textContent = 'Download error: ' + e.message;
  })
}
```

**Aborting from Blazor**

The problem becomes how to call `abort` from .NET. This becomes easy if the script is loaded as a *module*, as the [JavaScript isolation in JavaScript modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-6.0#javascript-isolation-in-javascript-modules) section shows. In that case we can add an `abort` method to the module that calls the `AbortController`'s `abort` .

*Warning* Air programming based on the documentation

```
var controller = new AbortController();
var signal = controller.signal;

abortDownload() {
  controller.abort();
  console.log('Download aborting');
});

function download(url,filenamme) {
  ...
  fetch(url, {signal})
    .then( res => res.blob() )
    .then( blob => {
        const file = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        const a = document.createElement("a");
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.href = exportUrl;
        a.download = filename;
        a.target = "_self";
        a.click();
        URL.revokeObjectURL(exportUrl);
    ...
  }).catch(function(e) {
   console.log('Download error: ' + e.message);
  })
}
```

Scripts and modules are typically imported after the first render, to ensure the page has rendered and all Javascript calls will succeed. That's not strictly necessary here :

```
@implements IAsyncDisposable
...
private IJSObjectReference module;
private CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    module = await _jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", 
            "./scripts.js");
    await module.InvokeVoidAsync("download", cts.Token, url,filename);
    
}

private async Task AbortAsync()
{
    //In case we navigate away before the module is loaded
    if(module!=null)
    {
        await module.InvokeVoidAsync("abortDownload");
    }
}
```

When disposing, `AbortAsync` must be called to cancel the `fetch` before calling signaling the CancelationTokenSource:

```
public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
{
    await AbortAsync();
    cts.Cancel();
    cts.Dispose();
}
```

All this async juggling is needed because `IJSRuntime` is used, which only provides async operations. This makes sense especially in Blazor Server, where Javascript calls have to be sent to the client's browser for execution.

Blazor WASM projects can use [IJSInProcessRuntime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.jsinterop.ijsinprocessruntime?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) instead which provides both synchronous and asynchronous methods. The synchronous methods are actually faster than the async ones.

In that case, `Abort` and `Dispose` could remain synchronous:

```
@inject IJSInProcessRuntime _jsRuntime
@implements IDisposable
...
private void  Abort()
{
    //In case we navigate away before the module is loaded
    if(module!=null)
    {
        module.InvokeVoid("abortDownload");
    }
}

public void Dispose()
{
    Abort();
    cts.Cancel();
    cts.Dispose();
}
```

Furthermore, [CancellationToken.Register](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken.register?view=net-5.0) could be used to call `Abort` :

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    module = await _jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", 
            "./scripts.js");

    var ct=cts.Token;
    ct.Register(()=>Abort());

    await module.InvokeVoidAsync("download", ct, url,filename);
    
}

public void Dispose()

    cts.Cancel();
    cts.Dispose();
}
```